# How to put SQL request in QueryBuilder and avoid ``?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have this SQL request in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM pt WHERE id=98 ORDER BY FIELD (position, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5)
```

and I need to make a query in Yii2. When I write

```
 'query' => Pt::find()->where(['id' => $model->id])
        ->OrderBy('FIELD (`position`, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5)')
```

I receive

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 20' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `pt` WHERE `id`=98 ORDER BY FIELD (`position`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`, `5)` LIMIT 20
```

How to avoid `` in request?

Comment: Try `->OrderBy('FIELD (position, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yii\db\Expression` class as it'll help you to insert RAW code (without formatting it in generated queries), but be cautious! Do not insert user input as RAW in DB queries, being that it leads to severe vulnerabilities.

The working code looks as follow:

```
'query' => Pt::find()->where(['id' => $model->id])
        ->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (`position`, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5)'))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I use it only for output in GridView.

Comment: It's my pleasure!